# How to convert an integer to a date type in dolphindb？

Tags: dolphindb

for example , I have a  integer x , How to convert it to DATE type?

```
x = 20200101
```

my expected result is :

```
d = 2020.01.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the integer to string and then use `datetimeParse` to convert it to a DATE object.

```
d = x.string().datetimeParse("yyyyMMdd")
```